# What are the advantages of MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, upgrade

Are there any advantages that should motivate an established MVC 3 shop with a full stack to upgrade to MVC 4 or 5?  We've been using MVC 3 for quite a while and don't feel like we really need "new functionality".

I'm looking for the type of advantage the Razor brought to views when MVC 3 was introduced over MVC 2.

Answer (score 4):

It really depends on your intended usage. They've been introducing new features which may be of interest to some people, but probably not to others.

For example, if you're starting a new project, you might benefit from the Bootstrap-based default templates. I've heard that they've got a new authentication model that makes it much easier to do things like OAuth and such, too.

If you're often using your controllers as restful APIs to provide JsonResults to a rich UI, you'll probably like WebApi.

If you find that your system is liable to hit its thread limit because it's getting a lot of requests which mostly do pass-throughs to I/O operations (requests to other web services, or calls to the database), then you might appreciate that controller actions can now return `Task<>`s that work asynchronously.

There are a handful of other features that are new since v3, and they pretty much all fall under the same category: they'll be useful to some folks, not so much to others.

One final benefit that you might derive from upgrading to .5 is that if .6 has a *must-have* feature you'll have already worked out the kinks in upgrading the last two versions, and it might make the transition to other future versions less painful.

Comment: The release notes are always the best place to determine if you should upgrade. For MVC4 see http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/mvc4-release-notes. For MVC5 see http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc5.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on MVC 4 and have used the WebAPI extensively. I'd like to move to MVC 5 for the attibute routing.. (currently, routing is configured in a separate configuartion file called by Global.asax at application_start)

Take a look at the attribute routing which they've built into WebAPI 2. See how routes are declared right alongside their methods in this sample [stolen directly from MSDN](http://www.asp.net/visual-studio/overview/2013/release-notes#TOC6):

```
public class MoviesController : ApiController 
{ 
    [Route("movies")] 
    public IEnumerable<Movie> Get() { } 

    [Route("actors/{actorId}/movies")] 
    public IEnumerable<Movie> GetByActor(int actorId) { } 

    [Route("directors/{directorId}/movies")] 
    public IEnumerable<Movie> GetByDirector(int directorId) { } 
}
```